# Android TabHost equivalent to setIndex

Tags: android, android-tabhost

i wanna change the current activated Tab of a TabHost.

There were some answers here on SOF, but they dont work, since they all use setCurrentTab.

I have a Map with marker and if i click on one, this function gets called:

```
public void onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    findViewById(R.id.createNewMarker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.tab_host).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The change of the Visibility works flawless, but when i tried to add `findViewById(R.id.tab_host).setCurrentTab(1)` the Method seem to not exists.

What is the currect way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById(R.id.tab_host)` returns a `View` class. `TabHost` is a subclass of `View`. To use `TabHost` methods on object, which is stored as `View`, but is a `TabHost` in fact, you have to **cast it** to `TabHost`:

```
((TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tab_host)).setCurrentTab(1)
```